# Рандомное заполнение массива

Tags: случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Не могу разобрать, как заполнить массив числами от -0,9 до 0,9? Помогите, кому не сложно

Comment: Добавьте деталей в вопрос. К примеру с каким интервалом, что провобавли уже сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку язык не указан, расскажу в общих чертах.

Вначале вы должны инициализировать генератор случайных чисел, затем, в зависимости от того, в каком диапазоне он возвращает случайные числа, равномерно-непрерывно преобразуем систему координат. Например, на Delphi:

```
Uses System.Math;
  const
    Count = 10000; // размер массива
var
  ar:array[0..Count-1] of double;
  i:integer;
<...>
  Randomize; // инициализируем генератор случайных чисел
  for i:=0 to Count do  // C
     ar[i]:=RandomRange(-4000000,4000000)*0.9/4000000;  // получаем случайное число в диапазоне от -4000000 до 4000000, затем сужаем диапазон, всего можем получить до 8 миллионов случайных чисел
```

в старом паскале нет такой полезной функции, как RandomRange, там пришлось бы делать так:

```
   ar[i]:=Random(4000000)*1.8/4000000 - 0.9;
```

А вот так, к примеру, в C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> // чтобы воспользоваться функцией time()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double randomDigits[1000] = {};
<...>       
    srand(time(NULL)); // инициализируем генератор случайных чисел системным временем
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        randomDigits[i] = rand()*1.8/32767-0.9; 0..32767 такой диапазон случайных чисел, возвращаемых функцией rand()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

На каком языке вы не написали. Реализовал на php

```
<?php 
$array = array(); // создаём пустой массив
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){ // создаём кол-во ячеек в массиве или сколько будет у нас образовано случайных чисел
$from = -9; // определяем границы целых чисел
$lie = 9;
$result = rand( $from, $lie) / 10 ; // создаём случайное число и приводим к десятым
$array[] = $result; // дописываем в массив
}

?>
```

Comment: Диапазон маловат: у вас получится всего лишь 19 разных случайных чисел. А если нужно заполнить массив в 10000 элементов?

Comment: Для меня очевидно, что это не проблема :) меняем for($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++){ и меняем $from = -9; $lie = 9; на +- 90000 и $result = rand( $from, $lie) / 10  делим на 100000

Comment: К тому же в условии не было ограничений и в задание я вижу желание понять, как это делается, а не играть с объёмами.